# React: Update a component's state after fetch delete

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update a component's state after a `fetch` call that deletes a row from the app's database.

I am new to react so not sure how to do this (do I need to call the get fetch event again?)

The way I am running it currently returns this error:

```
EditRecipe.jsx:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

Here is my code:

```
export default function RecipeList() {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([])

  const recipeSetter = () => {
    fetch('/api/recipes')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setRecipes(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    recipeSetter()
  }, [])

  const deleteRecipe = (e, id) => {
    console.log(id)
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('/api/recipes/delete', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id,
      }),
    }).then(() => setRecipes(recipeSetter())) //this is where the trouble is
  }

  const recipeList = recipes.map((recipe, idx) => (
    <React.Fragment key={idx}>
      <div className="recipe">
        <span>
          <Link to={'/edit/' + recipe.id}>{recipe.recipe_name}</Link>
        </span>
        <span
          className="delete"
          onClick={(evt) => deleteRecipe(evt, recipe.id)}
        >
          Delete
        </span>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recipeSetter()` is a function that will re-fetch the list from the backend, it will take some time to do that fetch, and then will set the state.

Because it's asynchronous, it returns immediately, but it returns `undefined` (doesn't have anything that's returning)

When you call `setRecipes(recipeSetter())`, recipeSetter starts the fetch and returns undefined. So essentially you are calling `setRecipes(undefined)`, which sets the state to undefined and everything blows up.

Just call `recipeSetter()` without the `setRecipes`

Answer (score 0):

It is because recipeSetter() does not return an Array. Please try the following code

```
  const deleteRecipe = (e, id) => {
    console.log(id)
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('/api/recipes/delete', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        id,
      }),
    }).then(() => recipeSetter()) 
  }
```